# Where can I find the JDBC driver for Progress OpenEdge 10.1?

Tags: driver, openedge

Where can I download the JDBC driver for Progress OpenEdge 10.1?

I use *java* and *JDBC* if it is important.

I did not install database and I can not access to %DLC%\java\openedge.jar. My client use this database, but I need check connection using connection string. Can I download a free driver from internet?

Comment: Google is your friend http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/21246 :)

Comment: Thank you, I found this site:) May be I explained incompletely. I did not install database and I can not access to %DLC%\java\openedge.jar. My client use this database, but I need check connection using connection string. Can I download free driver from internet?

Comment: Ask you client for the jar?

Comment: I just installed openedge and they arent anywhere to be found. I hate progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always test the Data Direct evaluation drivers:

[Data Direct](http://www.datadirect.com/support/product-documentation/downloads)